# What is the meaning of the last 2 sentences?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The last 2 sentences of [this article](http://www.english-test.net/toeic/listening/a_radio_commercial_for_window_installations.html#TOEIC_Listening_Comprehension) say `That's 888-972-SEAL. Tell 'em Frank sent you.`.

What do they mean?

From the definition of [urbandictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=frank), *Frank* refers to a male who is extremely charming in manner because of their gentleman behavior. But I don't this definition suits the context.

Also, why does the speaker in the article say *SEAL* instead of *1059*? This makes the listeners harder to remember the phone number, doesn't it?

Comment: 7325, not 1059. Right?

Comment: @NVZ. Where does 7325 come from?

Comment: I should know what a [phone keypad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_keypad) look like when reading this article.

Comment: not when you read it, but you'll need to know a telephone keypad when you dial it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the article, we are told that the guy talking is named 'Frank Miller'.

As such, 'tell'em Frank sent you' means that when you go to the shop, you should tell the people there that Frank sent you, as in Frank Miller told you to go there. You may receive a discount or something similar for doing so, or it's to let the store know if their radio adverts are working.

As for the 888-972-SEAL, most people actually find it easier to remember letter strings, especially words, rather than a string of numbers. As such, rather than having to remember a 10 number sequence, you only have to remember a 6 number sequence followed by a word, which many will find much much easier.

It's also a case of product association. The windows they are selling are called 'Seal' windows. It's similar to the UK reverse dial number, 0800-REVERSE

Comment: Thank you, now I understand the last sentence of this article.

Comment: But if a customer just remembers *888-972-SEAL*, how can he/she dials the correct phone number to get a free estimate?

Comment: SEAL stands for the letters on the dial pad. In this case, 7325. It seems like both 888-972-1059 and 888-972-7350 are being used by this company, it's just the second is easier to remember. The only other possibility is that the transcript is incorrect and 888-972-1059 is wrong.